DKIM Failure in Gsuite when passing thru SMTP RELAY
Hi folks need help is resolving a DKIM failure issue. we are using Gsuite email solution. However we also have secure email gateway to scan outbound emails. the flow of an outbound email is as below
Gmail (mail-qt1-f198.google.com) --> secure email gateway - SEG (local server) (PostFix) --> Gmail SMTP Relay (smtp-relay.gmail.com) --> Internet Recipient
If I don't setup the DKIM key in Gsuite the message is signed using the universal default DKIM key of Gsuite (*.20230601.gappssmtp.com) and the recipient sees the result as DKIM pass, but when i create a DKIM key in Gsuite for my domain the recipient sees the result as "dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)" which is treated as fail.
There is no issue with the DNS required as i have verified that with MXtool DKIM checker
Any idea how DKIM would work in this configuration. Will there be two level of signatures (once when Gmail sends it to SEG) and then when GMAIL SMTP relay sends it out? But at the recipient end in the header I don't see multiple DKIM signatures
The SEG servers folks assure us that they are not making any changes. Which is correct because with the GMAIL default DKIM key it works fine.
Thanks
